# Display 3 buttons in a row for dynamic number of buttons in android

Tags: android, mobile-application, android-developer-api

I am trying to display dynamic buttons on my android app UI.

I can generate the button dynamically.

**I want 3 buttons in each row as horizontally. So lets say i have 9 buttons to be generated; I want to display 3 buttons in each row. So there should be 3 horizontal rows with each row containing 3 buttons.**

I am struggling to display ONLY 3 buttons in each row.

Here is my sample code :

```
private void generateRedemptionButton(List<RedemptionType> redemptionTypeList){
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int i = 0; i < redemptionTypeList.size(); i++) {
        LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayoutChild.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayoutChild.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        if(i<=3){
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                Button button = new Button(this);
                button.setText("Some text");
                linearLayoutChild.addView(button);
            }
            linLayout.addView(linearLayoutChild);
        }
    }
    linearLayout.addView(linLayout);
}
```

But its all displaying in vertical one line? I have changed with horizontal properties; and for this all buttons are displayed in one horizontal line. So same issue!

Your feedback will help me to sort out the issue.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You don't want them horizontally in a row or vertically in a row, so what's the goal?

Comment: I want 3 buttons in each row as horizontally. So lets say i have 9 buttons to be generated; I want to display 3 buttons in each row. So there should be 3 horizontal rows with each row containing 3 buttons. Do you get it ?

Comment: @MaxBlue if you need an example let me know. I would be more thna happy to help

Comment: @MirianaItani hi thanks. Please show me the example

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create multiple LinearLayouts within the layouts.

-Main parents LinearLayout - vertical

-- Row 1 Linear Layout - horizontal

--- Row 1 button, button, button

-- Row 2 Linear Layout - horizontal

--- Row 2 button, button, button

Comment: i know the thing.but can't display from code point of view. Show me how to do that?

Comment: He just told you how. Now look into creating LinearLayouts programatically.

Comment: Got it..let me give a try

Comment: updated with LinearLayout[] linearLayoutChild = new LinearLayout[redemptionTypeList.size()]; But its crashing?

Comment: Please post the log - can edit the initial question if formatting is a problem

Comment: @BR89 everything is posted

Comment: Are there crash logs to go along with it or any errors thrown?

Comment: @BR89 Error is Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Comment: Hm.. that error is caused by having more array indexes than an array is initialized for. Do you have any arrays that can be swapped to arraylists?

Comment: Sorry, can you do it using sample input lets say 9. Then code it and show me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm actually not certain. With that error we're looking for an Array that is setup for X spaces and you've essentially created X + 1(or more) indexs

Comment: Forget about my error. Can you show me how to display 9 buttons with 3 rows?